# Firebase notifications not working in android 10

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

I'm facing push notifications issue with android 10.

I tried to use push notifications with android 11 in my emulator, but the mobile device I have , it has android 10 with this version didn't work.

If I install the app on Android 11, works very smooth.

What could be the problem?

I am using firebase in flutter mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the minsdk version in build.gradle file.